# parse string by the last occurrence of the character before another character in python

Tags: python, string

I have the following string that I need to split into smaller ones in a correct way:

```py
s = "A=3, B=value one, value two, value three, C=NA, D=Other institution, except insurance, id=DRT_12345"
```

I cannot do the following, since I need to split only on the last "," before the "="

```py
s.split(",")
```

My desired outcome is the following:

```py
out = ["A=3",
 "B=value one, value two, value three", 
"C=NA",
 "D=Other institution, except insurance", 
"id=DRT_12345"]
```

Comment: That's pretty close to being ambiguous. I'd recommend adding quotes or escapes to the language to avoid the problem, and then use a real parser.

Answer (score 2):

Following the structure of your string, you can use `re.findall`:

```
import re

re.findall(r'\S+=.*?(?=, \S+=|$)', s)
```

```
['A=3',
 'B=value one, value two, value three',
 'C=NA',
 'D=Other institution, except insurance',
 'id=DRT_12345']
```

The pattern uses a lookahead to determine when to stop matching for the current key-value pair.

```
\S+      # match or more non-whitespace characters 
=        # ...followed by an equal sign
.*?      # match anything upto...
(?=      # regex lookahead for
   ,     # comma, followed by
   \s    # a whitespace, followed by
   \S+   # the same pattern
   =
   |     # OR
   $     # EOL
)
```

Comment: How does '\S+=.*?(?=, \S+=|$)' regular expression work?

Comment: @Rfreak Added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Split on "the last comma before the equals" can be translated to a regex like this:

```
import re
out = re.split(r',(?=[^,]*=)', s)
```

That's a comma (`,`), followed by (a positive lookahead - `(?= .. )`) any number of non-comma characters (`[^,]*`) and then an equals sign (`=`).